# Check Date Validity while loading data from Excel

Tags: qlikview

I have a column in my Excel sheet containing date. I need to extract the 'Year' from it. However, there is inconsistency in the data. Some of the data is in the correct format (DD/MM/YYYY) while some of them are just Years(YYYY).

Sample Data:
10/11/2001
2002
2/12/2003
3/5/2004
2005

I need to load this data and fetch the Year.

My resultant date should be:
2001
2002
2003
2004
2005

I have tried multiple combination using Date(), Date#(), IsNum()
For EG: 
LOAD 
    Date,
    if(IsNum(Date#([Date],'MM/DD/YYYY')),'False','True') as DateYear
The above statement is always executong as true.

However, I have not yet found any suitable solution for this. Any other ideas for me to try out?

Answer (score 0):

in excel date is numérique value number af day from 1900 (windows)  ex: 10/11/2001  is 37205. Try with value comparaison if([Date] < 3000, 'Is Year', 'Is Date')

Answer (score 0):

dealing with Excels date format can be quite difficult.

Maybe try something like this this:

```
if (Len(Text([Date]))=4, Num([Date]), Year(Date#([Date], 'MM/DD/YYYY'))) as DateYear
```

Best regards,

Tom